# How to get billing address in order ID woocommerce as recipient for autoresponder?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, billing

We have an autoresponder which send thank you email for order status changed to completed. The autoresponder is firing but it is sending the email to all the subscribers in the list. We can't seem to figure out the right code to send it to the billing email only of the order who just got completed. We believe our code is wrong which results to null which results to sending to all subscribers.

We tried hundreds of codes already. This is the closes code I feel like we're getting to the right recipient.

```
function trigger_autoresponder($order_id, $data) {     
    $email = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', true );
    do_action( 'my_custom_hook', $email );    
}

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'trigger_autoresponder', 10, 1 );
```

We expect the autoresponder email will send the thank you email to the billing email address of the order that was changed to "completed" order status.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by email, you need to use the subscriber ID to trigger that per the documentation here.

Get the billing email -    [WC Order for getting billing email](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html)

Trigger autoresponder for a single subscriber  - [Trigger responder with hook](https://kb.mailster.co/working-with-action-hook-auto-responders/)

```
function trigger_autoresponder($order_id, $data) {     
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $email = $order->get_billing_email();

    if(!$email) return;

    $subscriber_id =  mailster( 'subscribers' )->query( array(
       'conditions' => array(
           array(
               'field' => 'email',
               'operator' => '=',
               'value' => $email,
           )
       )
   ));

   do_action( 'my_custom_hook', $subscriber_id );    
}

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'trigger_autoresponder', 10, 1 );
```

I don't have a way to test it and I think $subscriber_id might be an array.

The docs on the subscriber search are a little unclear - [MAILSTER SUBSCRIBER QUERY](https://kb.mailster.co/subscriber-query/)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Just tested the code and unfortunately it didn't send any autoresponder. Will continue further research and testing. We agree with you, mailster is unclear and considering the plugin is purchased, their support sucks. Didn't even help at all. We regret getting this plugin. Hopefully someone knows how to make this work. @KGreene